# Subnavigation in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I need a subnavigation on my pages. I inherit from base.html where the main navigation is located, but I don't know how to make a subnavigation which differs from page to page.

I've thought about making a template tag in which I can specify items to the subnavigation in each template file, and only output the subnavigation if any subnavigation items are specified. How do others do it?

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you have a separate block for subnavigation and override that block in child templates?

base.html

```
<a href="">Calls</a>
<a href="">Messages</a>
{% block subnav %}
{% endblock %}
```

calls.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block subnav %}
    <a href="">Outbound calls</a>
    <a href="">Inbound calls</a>
{% endblock %}
```

messages.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block subnav %}
    <a href="">Sent messages</a>
    <a href="">Recieved messages</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: +1, that's what I would propose. You can use your views as you (most likely) do now, and it has the added benefit that you can easily include asynchronous updates later on if you surround your block with a div (e.g. `<div id="subnav">{% block subnav %}{% endblock %}</div>`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to implement such could be to create a templatetag that takes an argument, for example the unique id or slug of the current page in the page tree.

E.g.

```
@register.simple_tag
def subnavigation_for_page(request, page_id, *args, **kwargs):
    qs = Page.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    current_page = qs.get(id=page_id)
    sub_navigation = list()
    for page in qs.filter(level__gt=current_page.level):
        if page.level > current_page.level:
            sub_navigation.append(page)
    return sub_navigation
```

You could extend the example to return the rendered navigation as html or use the 'as' node to return a variable and define the html within the template itself.

Package that might be of interest:

[django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt)